# Linux installation, how to partition for install with a raid setup?

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, grub, debian-bookworm

This question is about how to install Linux and create a raid setup as part of the installation. I am trying to install Debian 12, although this question is probably quite generalizable.

As part of the installation procedure, one of the steps is to configure disks and partitions.

I would like to create a raid 1 scheme and install to that.

What I don't understand is what order to do things in.

- Should I create a raid 1 first or partitions first?
- Should the raid 1 space be created from disks or partitions? (ie things like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sda1`

---

I tried:

- creating two new partition schemes, one for each disk, wiping all existing partitions on those disks
- creating a raid from the disks
- creating partitions on top of the raid

I also tried:

- the reverse procedure, creating two identically partitioned disks, first, and creating raid partitions from those partitions

Neither of these seemed to work, and the installation failed when trying to install the grub bootloader.

The error message was "grub install dummy failed"

In both cases I tried all combinations of the below:

- single partition setup
- separate EFI partition
- separate EFI and `/boot` partitions

---

Hardware:

I am trying to install this system on a AMD Ryzen 5 system.

- 5700G
- Asus Tuf B550M

I don't think this system supports anything other than UEFI mode. I had a look around the BIOS and couldn't find a legacy mode. The Debian installer I am using, doesn't seem to have a legacy mode, so I strongly suspect, but couldn't determine exactly, that the system installer has booted in UEFI mode.

Comment: I re-attempted this on another system recently, and opted to use Ubuntu Server, although I believe the required steps should be similar. I don't know how to setup the non-raid boot partitions exactly, yet. Ubuntu Server does some special setup for this by itself. It's not clear to me how those boot partitions should be setup. See this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJzHpc1kQW4